# how can i write a python code for give row and column and print 10101 and 01010 pattern

Tags: python, python-3.x

i want to write a python code for give row and column from input and print a pattern like this photo:
[image]

i write this code but this just show 10101 :

```
rows = int(input("Please Enter the total Number of Rows  : "))
columns = int(input("Please Enter the total Number of Columns  : ")) 
for i in range(1, rows + 1):
for j in range(1, columns + 1):
    if(j % 2 == 0):          
        print('0', end = '  ')
    else:
        print('1', end = '  ')
print()
```

thanks for your attention...☺♥

Comment: you've worked out how to identify alternate columns. use the same to identify alternate rows and handle them differently.

Comment: Please revise your posted code. Indentation is part of the code.

Comment: Try using the sum of both the row and column in the if condition. (Please, correct the indentation)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to consider both column and row index for correct solution.

```
rows = int(input("Please Enter the total Number of Rows  : "))
columns = int(input("Please Enter the total Number of Columns  : ")) 
for i in range(1, rows + 1):
    for j in range(1, columns + 1):
        if((j + i) % 2 == 1):          
            print('0', end = '  ')
        else:
            print('1', end = '  ')
    print()
```

Or shorter version

```
for i in range(1, rows + 1):
    for j in range(1, columns + 1):
            print((i + j + 1)%2, end = '  ')
    print()
```

Comment: Even shorter with ```range(rows)``` and ```range(columns)``` :)